# Truncate on x-overflow inside list item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make the nice `text-overflow: ellipsis;` work on long names (class `name`) in my list, adding to this CSS & HTML?  Note how the 55026 ID is wrapped below in an ugly fashion on the last time.

```css
.my-list {
  width: 275px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-group my-list">
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="60054">
   <span class="name">Item Name One</span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right">60054</span>
  </li>
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="00562">
   <span class="name">Item Name Two</span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right">00562</span>
  </li>
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="55026">
   <span class="name">A Really Long Item To Truncate </span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right">55026</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider a `row`/`col` configuration then add `overflow:hidden` to truncate the text:

```css
.my-list {
  width: 275px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.my-list>.row {
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-group my-list">
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item row ">
    <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-9">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="60054">
   <span class="name">Item Name One</span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right col-xs-3">60054</span>
  </li>
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item row">
    <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-9">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="00562">
   <span class="name">Item Name Two</span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right col-xs-3">00562</span>
  </li>
  <li class="preferred-payer list-group-item row">
    <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-9">
   <input id="option-one" type="checkbox" name="select" value="55026">
   <span class="name ">A Really Long Item To Truncate </span>
  </label>
    <span class="id pull-right col-xs-3">55026</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```